# i cant use python input to create mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

**I want to take input from user of creating a mysql database** *I cant use python input to create mysql database*[what i tryed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4NKG.png)

Getting this error please help [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5e3V.png)

Comment: Please provide code and exception as text not images, so we can try it from our sides

Comment: please don't post images of code. post the code itself.  You are attempting to use string formatting but have forgotten to call `.format(dbname)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`execute()` method parameters must be provided as a tuple, dict or a list :

```
cursor.execute(cdb, (dbname,))
```

And I think you can execute your query directly like :

### %-formatting

```
cdb = 'CREATE DATABASE %s' % dbname 
cursor.execute(cdb)
```

### F-strings

```
cdb = f'CREATE DATABASE {dbname}'
cursor.execute(cdb)
```

### str.format()

```
cdb = 'CREATE DATABASE {}'.format(dbname) 
cursor.execute(cdb)
```

Consider using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) when dealing with string that contains variables.

```
cdb = f'CREATE DATABASE {dbname}'
```

Comment: what is related with that f ? near cdb= f"create –

Comment: It's a way in python to format your strings, it's more readable and faster. I linked a tutorial explaining it

Comment: isnt it possible by that %s method? because it is a school project. i cant go out of league

Comment: Yeah ofc, I updated my answer with three types of formatting so you can choose what you want

Comment: i am also getting error in further code but cant post another question should i post in comment?
@SWEEPY

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75065236/19971191

Answer (score -1):

Try this way, this works correctly.

```
try:import mysql.connector as con
except ImportError:print("⚠ Install correctly mysql.connector")

db = con.connect(host="localhost",user="<username>",passwd="<password>")
cursor = db.cursor()

dbname = input("Enter ddbb name to create: ")
cdb = f"CREATE DATABASE {dbname}"

try:cursor.execute(cdb)
except NameError:print(NameError)
```

Comment: what is related with that f ? near cdb= f"create

Comment: By doing the `f"{}"` you are formatting the input into a text string

Comment: our teacher didnt told us about in school
thanks for helping

can you solve one more question

Comment: Of course, what do you need?

Comment: Write a program to implement python string functions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Haha, we are helping you, you thank us, and since we still haven't answered you due to lack of time, give us a vote?

Comment: If you want me to help you, lengthen what you need, the exercise is not understood in a single sentence.